# Whats is lambda method in Linq to XML?

Tags: lambda, linq-to-xml

Whats is lambda method in Linq to XML? how to use it? what is its main purpose ? in .net

Comment: what, does this means ? Natahn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very good article that describes lambda expressions and their uses.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx